# Configure cmake to choose compiler based on environment

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc, cmake

My current project directory looks like

```
myproject
/-build
/-include
  /-somefile.h
  /-somefile2.h
/-myproject.cpp
/-CMakeLists.txt
```

and current CMakeLists.txt looks like :

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.1)
project (myproject)
add_executable(myproject myproject.cpp)

set(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/build)
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}) 
set(PROJECT_INCLUDE_DIR ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

include_directories("${PROJECT_INCLUDE_DIR}")
include_directories("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}")
```

I want to build this project in both x64Windows and x64Linux environment while keeping single cmake file. Currently I have Visual Studio 13 CE in Win and gcc in Linux. Is it possible that Cmake could intelligently choose the correct compiler depending on OS? And what changes should I make to CMakeLists for that?

I'm using normal stuff like STL and vanilla C++ ( no os dependent libraries) if that matters. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to add conditional code for each compiler:

```
if("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "GNU")

# Set the C++ and linker flags to GCC specifics here.

elseif("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "MSVC")

# Set the C++ and linker flags to VC++ specifics here.

elseif("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "Clang")

# Set the C++ and linker flags to Clang specifics here.

elseif()
```

The right compiler is set automatically at least on linux. On windows I don't know. However you could always overwrite the selected compiler by the environment variables `CC` and `CXX`. This changes the cmake configuration. The changes will only affect new build configurations. So don't forget to delete your old one before selecting a new compiler.

Edit: The compiler must be of course in your `PATH` variable. Otherwise CMake will not find it correctly.